# Error While installing Foundry

Tags: solidity, error, foundry, installation

I'm getting an error while installing Foundry using this command

Command:

```
curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash
```

Error:

```
 ~/desktop/foundry
$ curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1942  100  1942    0     0   1318      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  1318Installing foundryup...

Warning: Failed to open the file C:/Users/Huzaifa: Permission denied
####################                                                      28.8%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Ahmed
```

I'm on window10 using GitBash normally and as an Administrator. But getting the same error.
I tried to install it using Visual Code but nothing changed.